# how to change position of textview with change the textview color

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Hey new in android just create an app in that change the text color after change position of the in list view, when I am changing the position of the ABC at the same time change the new position ABC "Assigning" to "Assigned" text with change Assigned color red.
please help me.

```
private class CurrentEmployeeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int layoutId;
    LayoutInflater liCurrentEmp;
    public CurrentEmployeeAdapter(CurrentEmployee currentEmployee, int activity_current_employee) {
        this.context=currentEmployee;
        this.layoutId=activity_current_employee;

        liCurrentEmp=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return SalesManNameArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if (convertView==null){
            convertView=liCurrentEmp.inflate(R.layout.current_employee_items,parent,false);
            v=convertView;
        }else {
            v=convertView;
        }
        TextView tvEmpName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_salesman_name);
        final TextView tvassingwork=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_assign_word);
        Button btnAssign=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_assign);

        btnAssign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        tvassingwork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (assignNo==1) {
                    tvassingwork.setText("Assigning");
                    tvassingwork.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                    assignNo=0;
                }else {
                    int i=position+1;
                    if(i >0) {

                        String moveName = SalesManNameArrayList.get(position);
                        SalesManNameArrayList.set(position, SalesManNameArrayList.get(position));
                        SalesManNameArrayList.remove(position);
                        SalesManNameArrayList.add(SalesManNameArrayList.size(), moveName);


                        tvassingwork.setText("Assigned");
                        tvassingwork.setTag(position-1);
                        tvassingwork.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                        assignNo=1;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        tvEmpName.setText(SalesManNameArrayList.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      tvassingwork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (assignNo==1) {
                tvassingwork.setText("Assigning");
                tvassingwork.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                assignNo=0;
            }else {
                int i=position+1;
                if(i >0) {

                    String moveName = SalesManNameArrayList.get(position);
                    SalesManNameArrayList.set(position, SalesManNameArrayList.get(position));
                    SalesManNameArrayList.remove(position);
                    SalesManNameArrayList.add(SalesManNameArrayList.size(), moveName);


                    tvassingwork.setText("Assigned");
                    tvassingwork.setTag(position-1);
                    tvassingwork.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                    assignNo=1;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

**runOnUIThread()** may helps you.

Comment: sathish i ok but after change Assigned color change only click position only, into change ABC position not change

Comment: sorry . i cant understand what you said?

Comment: Sathish, when i am click on assigning text is change the position of ABC to last of listview. At that same time i want to change the same row assiging to assinged text with color